# Rhythm notation converter (task #1)

Tags: c++, interview-questions, converting, music

About a year ago, I was given a C++ assignment as a preliminary job-interview test.

The assignment included 4 different tasks, from which I had to choose one.

I actually chose and completed 3 out of 4 tasks, but I did not pass the test.

I was not given any specific rejections, so I would like to get an unbiased opinion.

---

[image]

---

### My answer:

**File main.cpp:**

```
// --------------------------------
// Input (command-line):
// - Number of beats per bar
// - Number of notes per beat
// - A list of raw beat times
// --------------------------------
// Output (standard):
// - A list of formatted beat times
// --------------------------------

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static string Compute(int numOfBeatsPerBar,int numOfNotesPerBeat,double beatTime);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Input";
        return -1;
    }

    int numOfBeatsPerBar  = stoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfNotesPerBeat = stoi(argv[2]);

    for (int i=3; i<argc; i++)
    {
        double beatTime = stod(argv[i]);
        string sampTime = Compute(numOfBeatsPerBar,numOfNotesPerBeat,beatTime);
        cout<<beatTime<<' '<<sampTime<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

static string Compute(int numOfBeatsPerBar,int numOfNotesPerBeat,double beatTime)
{
    int barId  = (int)beatTime;
    beatTime   = (beatTime-barId)*numOfBeatsPerBar;
    int beatId = (int)beatTime;
    beatTime   = (beatTime-beatId)*numOfNotesPerBeat;
    int noteId = (int)beatTime;

    ostringstream oss;
    oss<<barId+1<<'.'<<beatId+1<<'.'<<noteId+1;
    if (beatTime > 0)
        oss<<'+';
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: I think the input should have been through stdin rather than command lines

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Possibly, but I doubt that it would make a difference as far as the point of rejecting the entire answer.

Comment: They likely shoved it into an automated test rig and when you printed out invalid input everytime they just gave up and gave you the fail.

Answer (score 2):

I think your condition for putting the '+' isn't right: it should be `beatTime-noteId > 0` instead of `beatTime > 0`.

For the given example there will be no difference in the output, but test it with  e.g. `4 4 1.125` as command line arguments: `1.125` matches a full 16th but your code prints `1.125 2.1.3+` instead of `1.125 2.1.3`.